# How to test Windows application that communicates with a Unix machine

Tags: unix

I wrote a windows desktop tool that is supposed to read / write files to a unix machine. The problem is that I don't have a unix machine to test it on. 
Is there something I can install on my windows machine that will mimic a remote unix machine and let me test my application?

Comment: You would have to install a virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed VMWare player. In VMWare player installed Lubunto. Works perfectly.